# Solving $ {L}_{1} $ Regularized Least Squares Over Complex Domain

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, regularization

I would like to solve the following [Regularized Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularized_least_squares) Problem (Very Similar to [LASSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics))):

$$ \arg \min_{x} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} $$

Where $ A \in {\mathbb{R}}^{m \times n} $ and $ b \in {\mathbb{R}}^{m} $.
For simplicity one could define $ f \left( x \right) = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} $ and $ g \left( x \right) = \lambda {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} $.

For $ x \in {\mathbb{R}}^{n} $ the solution can be achieved using [Sub Gradient Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgradient_method) or [Proximal Gradient Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximal_gradient_method).

My question is, how can it be solved for $ x \in {\mathbb{C}}^{n} $ (Assuming $ A \in {\mathbb{C}}^{m \times n} $ and $ b \in {\mathbb{C}}^{m} $)?
Namely if the problem is over the complex domain.

For instance, what is the Sub Gradient?
What is the Prox (Shrinkage of Complex Number)?

Thank You.

#### My Attempt for Solution 001

The Gradient of $ f \left( x \right) $ is given by:

$$ {\nabla}_{x} f \left( x \right) = {A}^{H} \left( A x - b \right) $$

The Sub Gradient of $ g \left( x \right) $ is given by:

$$ {\partial}_{x} g \left( x \right) = \lambda \operatorname{sgn} \left( x \right) = \lambda \begin{cases}
\frac{x}{ \left| x \right| } & \text{ if } x \neq 0 \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x = 0
\end{cases} $$

Namely it is the Complex [Sign Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Then, the Sub Gradient Method is given by:

$$ {x}^{k + 1} = {x}^{k} - {\alpha}_{k} \left( {A}^{H} \left( A {x}^{k} - b \right) + \lambda \operatorname{sgn} \left( {x}^{k} \right) \right) $$

Where $ {\alpha}_{k} $ is the step size.

Yet it won't converge to CVX Solution for this problem.

Remark on Attempt 001

I think I understood why it doesn't work well.
The [Absolute Value Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) in the Complex Domain is (Quoted from Wikipedia [Absolute Value Derivative Section](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Absolute_value&section=7#Derivative)):

[image]

Comment: @LinAlg, Why do you think so?

Comment: I was wrong, see my answer.

Comment: @LinAlg, I remember to do it. I will try it today and will mark it / comment accordingly. I really appreciate your efforts. By the way, My attempt was right. Just for strange reason solving those problems on the Complex Domain requires 2-3 folds more iterations. I really don't understand why.

Comment: Try an interior point solver for predictable performance. If you use matlab, YALMIP is a convenient way of formulating these problems.

Comment: @LinAlg, I'm trying to build a solve my self using Sub Gradient and Proximal Sub Gradient method. I actually made it for the Complex Formulation above (I will post code later). Yet it is so slow! I will try another formulation today.

Comment: You can build an interior point solver yourself too. For problems like these you may do better than existing solvers due to the structure of your problem. In my experience, subgradient and proximal gradient solvers are just not as fast, and are only useful for extremely large instances where other algorithms cannot be applied.

Comment: @LinAlg, In my case the vector $ x $ might have ~2000-4000 Elements and the Matrix $ A $ can be something like $ 200 \times 4000 $. Do you think for this case Interior Points will be faster? I tried CVX and for the Real Domain it is much slower than Accelerated Proximal Gradient.

Comment: What solution time are you hoping for? For the real domain it should be solvable in 10 seconds on a core i7-6700 in the real domain.

Comment: Using Accelerated Proximal Sub Gradient I think it can be done much faster. At least when I compared to CVX.

Comment: This comment comes somewhat late, but complex differentiation is very tricky, and **both** of your (sub)gradients require conjugation and rescaling, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\nabla_x f &= \frac 12\Big(A^H(Ax-b)\Big)^* \\
\partial_x g &= \lambda\,\Big({\rm sgn}(x)\Big)^* \\
}$$
With these changes your algorithm should converge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $A = B + Ci$, $b=c+di$ and $x=y+zi$. The objective function is
$$
\begin{align*}f(x) &= ||(B+Ci)(y+zi)-c-di||_1^2 + \lambda ||y+zi||_1 \\
&= ||By-Cz-c+(Cy+Bz-d)i||_2^2 + \lambda ||y+zi||_1 \\
&= ||By-Cz-c||_2^2 + ||Cy+Bz-d||_2^2  + \lambda \sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{y_j^2+z_j^2} \\
&= \left\Vert\begin{pmatrix}B \\ -C \end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix}y\\z\end{pmatrix}-c\right\Vert_2^2 + \left\Vert\begin{pmatrix}C \\ B \end{pmatrix}^T\begin{pmatrix}y\\z\end{pmatrix}-d\right\Vert_2^2  + \lambda \sum_{j=1}^n \left\Vert\begin{pmatrix}e_j^T & 0 \\ 0 & e_j^T \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}y\\z\end{pmatrix}\right\Vert_2
\end{align*}
$$
where $e_j$ is the $j^{th}$ unit vector. Finding the subgradient is now straightforward:
$$
\begin{align*}
2\begin{pmatrix}B \\ -C \end{pmatrix} \left(\begin{pmatrix}B \\ -C \end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix}y\\z\end{pmatrix}-c\right) &+ 2\begin{pmatrix}C \\ B \end{pmatrix}\left(\begin{pmatrix}C \\ B \end{pmatrix}^T\begin{pmatrix}y\\z\end{pmatrix}-d\right) \\
&+ \lambda \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\begin{pmatrix}e_j^T & 0 \\ 0 & e_j^T \end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix}e_j^T & 0 \\ 0 & e_j^T \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}y\\z\end{pmatrix}}{\left\Vert\begin{pmatrix}e_j^T & 0 \\ 0 & e_j^T \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}y\\z\end{pmatrix}\right\Vert_2}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks, fixed. What do you mean by 'more general approach'?

Comment: The variables are now $y$ and $z$.

Comment: There are $2n$ variables. I assumed that if you can optimize over $5$ variables, that you can also do $10$ and that you were able to take the derivative. I have now added one extra step. You can consider the vector [y;z] as the optimization variable if that helps.

Comment: There you go...