# Difference Between $ {L}_{1} $ Regularized Least Squares Optimization Problem for Real and Complex Domain

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers, convex-optimization

I have implemented a Least Squares Optimization with $ {L}_{1} $ Norm Regularization for the problem. My reference was - [Least Squares Optimization with L1 Norm Regularization by Mark Schmidt](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/Documents/2005_Notes_Lasso.pdf).

The paper discuss the problem of solving:

$$ {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} $$

The paper assume all variables are under the real domain. Namely $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \; x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \; b \in \mathbb{R}^{m} $.
How would one solve the problem over the complex domain where $ A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}, \; x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}, \; b \in \mathbb{C}^{m} $?

Comment: Replace $x$ with $ x+ iy$ and optimize over $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @LinAlg so if we consider  real and imaginary part as two different variable,both should converse?

Comment: What do you mean by converse? Also see my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079610/solving-ell-1-regularized-least-squares-over-complex-domain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\DeclareMathOperator{\prox}{prox}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\newcommand{\MyParen}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
\newcommand{\MyBrack}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
\newcommand{\MyBrace}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\newcommand{\MyNorm}[2]{{\left\| #1 \right\|}_{#2}}
\newcommand{\MyNormSqr}[2]{{\left\| #1 \right\|}_{#2}^{2}}
\newcommand{\MyNormTwo}[1]{\MyNorm{#1}{2}}
\newcommand{\MyNormTwoSqr}[1]{\MyNormSqr{#1}{2}}
\newcommand{\MyAbs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}
\newcommand{\MyCeil}[1]{\left \lceil #1 \right \rceil}
\newcommand{\MyFloor}[1]{\left \lfloor #1 \right \rfloor}
\newcommand{\MyProd}[2]{\langle #1, #2 \rangle}
\newcommand{\MyUndBrace}[2]{\underset{#2}{\underbrace{#1}}}
% \newcommand{\RR}[1]{\mathds{R}^{#1}} % Asaf's Style
\newcommand{\RR}[1]{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}
\newcommand{\EE}[1]{\mathbb{E} \MyBrack{#1}}$$

Solve the problem

$$\begin{equation} \label{eq:LSL1ObjFun}
 \arg \min_{x} \left\{ \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \right\}
\end{equation}$$

Where $ A \in {\mathbb{C}}^{m \times n} $, $ x \in {\mathbb{C}}^{n} $ and $ b \in {\mathbb{C}}^{m} $.

For simplicity defining:

$$\begin{equation} \label{eq:LSL1Fun}
 f \left( x \right) = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \tag{eq:LSL1Fun}
\end{equation}$$

The $ {\ell}_{1} $ norm of a complex vector is defined as:

$$ \MyNorm{z}{1} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \sqrt{\Re^{2} \MyParen{ {z}_{k} } + \Im^{2} \MyParen{ {z}_{k} } } $$

By definition $ A = B + i C $, $ x = y + i z $ and $ b = c + i d $.
By setting $ \hat{A} = \begin{bmatrix} B & -C \\ C & B \end{bmatrix} $ and $ \hat{b} = \begin{bmatrix} c \\ d \end{bmatrix} $ one could rewrite Equation \ref{eq:LSL1Fun} as:

$$ f \left( y, z \right) = \frac{1}{2} \MyNormTwo{ \hat{A} \begin{bmatrix} y \\ z \end{bmatrix} - \hat{b} }^{2} + \lambda \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \sqrt{ {y}_{j}^{2} + {z}_{j}^{2} } $$

From here one could use classic methods to solve the problem.